# Can pip and setuptools install icons and launchers?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi

Is it possible to install icons and launchers using a `setup.py` file, setuptools and PyPI? Like, I'm talking about including `.desktop` launcher files for Python scripts included in the package and `.svg` icons for those launchers. Usually the `.desktop` files would be installed at `/usr/share/applications` and the icons would be installed at `/usr/share/icons`.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501597/how-to-distribute-desktop-files-and-icons-for-a-python-package-in-gnome-with)?Seems to provide some type of solution. However it's a very old answer. Maybe it gives you a starting point to search for more up-to-date approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible with `data_files` but not recommended. Think about a package installed into a separate environment created with `virtualenv` — users will be surprised if such a package installs files outside that separate environment.

Hence advice: distinguish pip-installable package that must be self-contained and must not install anything beyond python code and files required for the code (could be installed with `package_data`) from full-blown installable package created with installer builders like RPM or DEB.

Comment: shouldn't `MANIFEST.in` be enough for [adding any non-code file](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non-code-files.html)?

Comment: You couldn't install `.desktop` with `MANIFEST.in` or `package_data` into `/usr` or `$HOME`. `MANIFEST.in` and `package_data` are for installing into `site-packages`. `data_files` can be used to install anywhere, but it's not recommended.

Comment: So the idea is that, if you have non code files like some icons or images for a GUI app, then you can keep those files in `site-packages` using `MANIFEST.in`. And if your package itself installs other things while installing itself, then MANIFEST.in is useless? Is this understanding correct ?

Comment: It's not useless, it's for a different purpose. `MANIFEST.in` and `package_data` are for installing into `site-packages`, `data_files` is to install anywhere.

Comment: Pardon me for asking this as I started with packaging just a couple of days ago, but if something is part of a library, then shouldn't it also be installed in `site-packages` ? Could you give me some cases in which installing it elsewhere would be desirable?

Comment: The question mentions `.desktop` files and icons. Those belong to the desktop directories in `/usr` or `$HOME`, not to `site-packages`.

Comment: Okay, so now I understand this. You want to have some file and an icon in `.desktop` so as to have a shortcut in the launcher or make it appear like any other program you install in linux? So in this case it is imperative that you install these files in `.desktop` directory? Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: *You want* Not me, but the OP (original poster). The rest is right.